# Unity / Vuforia How to find seek position in a video?

Tags: android, video, unity-game-engine, vuforia, seek

I'm trying to loop a video in a vuforia AR app, my first idea was to split the video in 2 parts and play them separately but there is a gap that happens when the first video ends and the player loads the second video

Searching in the Code I found the play function in VideoPlayHelper.cs

```
/// <summary>
    /// Request a movie to be played either full screen or on texture and at a given position
    /// </summary>
    public bool Play(bool fullScreen, float seekPosition)
    {
        // We use Unity's built-in full screen movie player
        if (fullScreen)
        {
            if (mFilename == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie(mFullScreenFilename, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFit);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return videoPlayerPlay(fullScreen, seekPosition);
        }
    }
```

Which means that I can seek and play from a given position, but I don't know how to find the seek position, is it a time value or a frame value?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself :)... It is a time value in seconds... so if you want to seek to 10.5 seconds then you just put that value:

```
video.play(false,10.5);
```